# Effect of calling Functions in c++ dll from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I have a C++ Protocol Stack dll(for serial communication) which exposes a class to a front application. Exposed class is like as shown below:

```
class ProtocolStack
{
public :
    void OpenRequest(Params);
    void SendData(Params);
    void CloseRequest(Params);
};
```

ProtocolStack Class creates different layers like PhysicalLayer as shown below.

```
class PhysicalLayer
{
private:
    int Baud_rate;
    string PortName;
public:
    void Send(string);
    void Receive();
 };
```

I want to use the same protocol stack for reading data parallely from different systems.
If i create a single object of Protocol Stack for parallel reading (from different ports) , when same function is called simultaneously from different threads will data segment allocated for each function call will be different?

It will corrupt the private variables of Physical Layer. right?

Do i need to maintain all data of each channel(parallel connection ) in each Layer?

I want to process data parallely . Is there any other way apart from creating another object of stack or maintaining all data related to connection in each layer?

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here to answer your questions. Anything on the stack within a function should be safe. Anything else (static variables at function, class, or global level, heap memory, member variables of a shared object, etc) and you need to worry. If each of those functions, for instance, creates a PhysicalLayer object, does it's work, and then exits allowing the PhysicalLayer to be destructed, and you might be fine.

Comment: @charlie Those things are handled . But I didn't show those here because that is not related with my question. What my question is whether Separate data attributes will be stored for same object when functions from the dll are called simultaneously. Those function may change each class attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the code is in a DLL is not relevant. Code is code. Regarding data sharing, data is only shared between threads if the code chooses to do so. If the code uses stack based or allocates its own heap based memory, then data is not shared. If the code stores its data at global scope, then data is shared between threads. That's the just the same if the code is written by you, or hosted in a third party library in a DLL.

The question boils down to the threading rules of the code. The code may not support threaded usage at all. The code may support threaded usage, so long as you follow certain rules. They only way to be sure is to consult the documentation of the code, hoping of course that the others actually documented their threading model.

---

In a comment to the question you say:

> My question is whether separate data attributes will be stored for same object when functions from the dll are called simultaneously.

No they will not. If you have two threads referring to the same object, then modifications of that object's data made by one thread will be visible by the other thread.

Comment: Suppose in One thread I called OpenRequest() with some params like baudrate to initialize PhysicalLayer and in other thread  i called the same function with different baud rate as parameters . What i wanted to do is parallel data downloading but there is no threading in stack. Can i download data from different COM ports with only one object of Physical Layer?

Comment: It depends entirely on the threading model of the library that you use. Which is information that we don't have. Your next task is to find out that threading model. Consult the library docs.

Comment: Currently Library only supports reading from only one system.

Comment: As I said, you'll need to obey the rules of the library. I'm not at all clear on what they are mind you, based on what you've said.